# How did Kroenen escape from Tarmagant Island the day Hellboy arrived?

Tags: hellboy

How did Kroenen escape from Tarmagant Island the day Hellboy arrived? He was hanging around one minute and gone the next. How did he get away?

[image: Kroenen]

Kroenen

Comment: There is no In universe explanation that I can deduce. He's impaled on a spike and then he is gone. It is just his abilities, gifted by the Elder Gods or Nazi occult practices and the need to be a formidable enemy threat. Same deal with his filled with sand body and clockwork heart, character specific attributes, in keeping with the author's vision and the nature of the story.

Comment: @IhorSypko Your comment would make a worthy answer. I couldn't find an in universe solution either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned very briefly in the official novelisation. After the implosion of the portal (and in the ensuing confusion) he "*managed to escape*", presumably by simply lifting himself off of the spikes and running away. The same scene also occurs in the script, again with his actual escape unseen by the camera.

**[Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Hellboy.html) (edited for brevity)**

> Kroenen flies through the air, hitting a stone wall, where two long
>   pieces of shrapnel pin him like an insect.
>
> The cosmic portal suddenly implodes! Nothing is left but a few burnt
>   rails and the metal glove, empty and smoking.
>
> Grigory and Ilsa are gone. And for now, so is Kroenen. Embedded in the
>   wall where he was pinned, two bloody rails, nothing more.

**[Official Novelisation:](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hellboy-Yvonne-Navarro/dp/0743492897)**

> Nothing was left behind but a few burned rails and Grigori's strange
>   metal glove, empty and sending a plume of smoke into the mist-soaked
>   air.
>
> Matlin looked around frantically, but Ilsa and Grigori were gone.
>   Sucked into the portal? There was no way to tell for sure. **Even
>   Kroenen had managed to escape, the only mark of his exit two
>   blood-covered shards of metal embedded firmly in the stone wall.**

Later in the film we discover that the extent of his injuries was sufficient to require him to replace most of his body with mechanical parts and black magic. There's no special indication that he used magic to escape though.